# Fancy/Clean way to use an Array created by toArray();

Tags: android, sqlite, contacts

mids contains 2 strings: a name and an id.  I want to fee my IN clause the IDs.  Any ideas how I might do this without iterating through a loop to build the array fed in as args?

```
private List<Contacts> getCntctList(List<GroupMembers> mids){
    List<Contacts> cntcts = new ArrayList<Contacts>();
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Object[] mIDs = mids.toArray();
    Cursor contactCur = cr.query(People.CONTENT_URI, null, "People._ID IN (?)", new String [] { mIDs.toString() } , People.NAME + " ASC");
    if (contactCur.getCount() > 0) {
        while (contactCur.moveToNext()) {
           ...
        }
    }
    return cntcts;
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that the GroupMembers object has two fields: name and id? So the `mids.toArray()` statement will generate an array of GroupMembers objects. And from that you want a statement that would generate a list of ids from the GroupMembers objects w/o using a loop?

Comment: Exactly.  :)  Can that be done?